# Get correct telephone properties from Azure AD using Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'am trying to get user phones from Azure AD using Graph API but without luck.

If I in Powershell use the MsOnline module and issue the following command:

```
  get-azureAdUser | select userPrincipalName,mobile,telephonenumber
```

I get a userlist including all the telephone numbers.

But if I in Graph use the command

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=userPrincipalName,mobilephone,businessphones
```

the telephone fields is empty. The list contains the same users, but much of the information is missing.

Is it possible to get the phone numbers using Graph API by using some other command?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check:

1. Please check access token you are using has necessary permissions. Refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#remarks-24) to learn about required permission to access.
   For example, you need to use either Directory.Read.All or User.Read.All. Both however require Admin Consent
2. Also consider Phone Numbers are not available for personal Microsoft Accounts (MSA). They're only returned for Work/School accounts (AAD)

If you still face issues, share request id and timestamp from Graph Explorer.